# Swift: Save UIDatePicker Date Into CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uidatepicker

I have an attribute in `CoreData` which accepts a date value. I just want to get the `UIDatePicker` date and save it in this format `dd/mm/yyyy`.
 But don't know how. Thanks

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: Constant.context!)

    newUser.setValue(self.txtName!.text, forKey: Constant.CDName)
    newUser.setValue(self.txtEmail!.text, forKey: Constant.CDEmail)
    newUser.setValue(self.txtPassword!.text, forKey: Constant.CDPassword)
    newUser.setValue(self.txtDob.text, forKey: Constant.CDDob) as! String

    do {
        try Constant.context?.save() }
```

So when I click on the `UITextfield` the `UIDatePicker` is open and I can select the date. Then when I click on the save button I want to save all above in my `CoreData`. I can save data expect the Date.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I find the correct way after trying couple of time. This is the code that help me out from this.

```
  let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
     let myString = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
     let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)

  let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: Constant.context!)

     newUser.setValue(self.txtName!.text, forKey: Constant.CDName)
     newUser.setValue(self.txtEmail!.text, forKey: Constant.CDEmail)
     newUser.setValue(self.txtPassword!.text, forKey: Constant.CDPassword)
     newUser.setValue(yourDate, forKey: Constant.CDDob)

        do {
            try Constant.context?.save()}
```

Again thanks for the help.

Comment: comment if you still face an issues.